# Updating probability distribution for decision making in game AI.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, artificial-intelligence

I'm programming an AI simulation where a car is randomly driving around a area. Within this area there are 5 repair shops. While driving, the car get's damaged (1% for every step). Once the damage of the car is 100%, it will find a shop to repair, while finding a repair shop the car takes no more damage.

For finding the shop, the car uses A* on a graph based on euclidean distance. The amount of nodes (steps) in the path is used to represent damage it would normally take when driving. The car always wants to be back on the road as soon as possible. So when a shop that repairs 80% is 30 nodes away, but a shop that repairs 70% is only 12 nodes away, it should prefer the 70%, although it repaired less, it's the best repair value to be back on the road as fast as possible.

The car makes a discision on what repair shop must be travelled to, based on it's experiences with those repair shops.

At the very start, the car doesn't know how good a shop might be, so the distribution of the shops is something like:

- Shop A : 20%
- Shop B : 20%
- Shop C : 20%
- Shop D : 20%
- Shop E : 20%

The formula to find the right spot is based on the average experience of that shop - the amount of node in the path(found with A*) from the car to that shop. It will then choose the shop with the highest percentage left.

- Shop A: average repair = 70%, distance = 35 nodes.
- Shop B: average repair = 55%, distance = 5 nodes.

Decision will be :

- Shop A : 70% - 35%(nodes) = 35%
- Shop B : 55% - 5%(nodes) = 50%.

50% is a better choice for the car, so it will choose B.

Different stores repair the car at different rates, these rates are unknown to the car.

- Shop A : Repairs between 20% and 100% at random.
- Shop B : Repairs between 30% and 80% at random.
- Shop C : Repairs 50%
- Shop D : Repairs between 30% and 80% at random.
- Shop E : Repairs between 20% and 100% at random.

The likelihood of the car going to one of these spots is updated each time it get's repaired.

My question here is: How to update the distribution of different shops, from the cars perspective, such that the repair cost is always taken into account. I have no prior knowledge in this subject and just hoping I can be pointed to the right direction from here.

Comment: I don't think this is clear.  First of all, I take it that there is a graph, or some such thing, which tells us how long it takes to get between various points?  Of course, the probabilities will depend on your location at that time...are you going to simulate all possible starting locations of the car?  Also, the utility function isn't clear.  How do I weigh a chance to get more of the repairs fixed against the new damage that occurs as I drive?  Though, how is the car even mobile with 100% damage?  In short, I think a lot of things need to be cleared up.

Comment: @lulu I've updated the question to explain the points you made!

Comment: There is still a lot that is unclear.  If the car is at $100\%$ damage, how are the travel costs assessed?  Presumably it is a bad idea to travel a long way just to get to my lucky shop, but how do we quantify that?  And how do we compare that cost against my preferences?  How do we assess the uncertainty in the repair?  Do you seriously mean that, say, in comparing $A$ and $E$ (which are equivalent) that I should take into account the fact that I got lucky at $A$ often?  That's a very bad utility function.

Comment: I think this problem is far too vague.  It's going to take a lot of work to get it into a form that admits a sensible answer.

Comment: It's more or less like you say, but that's just because of my lack of understand the subject and my lack of knowing what words and terms I must research. At the moment I wouldn't know a better solution than taking the luck at a shop, having said that, the travel costs are assessed by the amount of visited nodes, the damage taken is equal to the weight of the edge. 

That is also part of the question, there is alot wrong with my solution and how i tackle it but im stuck on the names of those subjects and where to look for.

Comment: What you have described is not a probability problem at all.  You give a simple deterministic function that defines the choice. Yes, this function is updated as repairs are done but not in any sort of sensible way (if you get unlucky one time you avoid the shop for no good reason).  For AI problems, typically, one seeks to optimize something or other, but that does not appear to be going on in your problem.